# PyCharm to use virtualenv and dependencies created by PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm, virtualenv

I have created a virtualenv using command prompt and have installed all my dependencies. How can I make PyCharm use the virtual env & dependencies created via command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link the virtualenv in PyCharm. 
In order to do this, go to:

```
File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter
```

Here, in the top right corner of the window, click on the *gear icon* and choose **Add**. 
Then, choose *Existing environment* option and navigate in your computer until you find the *python.exe* for your virtualenv.

Than confirm modifications clicking *Ok*. This should be enough.

If you want to use it in a PyCharm configuration, please do not forget to choose it in the *Python Interpreter* option.